# delete post hook not being fired when deling in wordpress dashboard admin

Tags: posts, customization

What I'm trying to do is to delete some post from a custom post type `bookitall_availabledate` after a post is deleted from custom post type `bookitall_bookings` in the admin dashboard.

I'm using delete_post hook: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post

**Here's some relevant code:** (tell me if you need more)

```
public function __construct() 
    {                        
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'loadlanguage' ) );
    }


public function loadlanguage() 
{                 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );        

    wp_enqueue_style(
        'bookitallcss',
        plugins_url( '/css/wibergsweb.css', __FILE__)
    );      

    //Load (if there are any) translations
    $loaded_translation = load_plugin_textdomain( 'bookitall-wp', false, 
    dirname( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '/lang/' );
    $this->init();
    $this->admin_init();
}      

public function admin_init() {

    add_filter('manage_edit-bookitall_bookings_columns', array($this, 'manage_allbookings_columns') );
    add_filter('manage_bookitall_bookings_posts_custom_column', array( $this, 'manage_allbookings_custom_fields'), 10, 2);

    add_filter('manage_edit-bookitall_roomtypes_columns', array($this, 'manage_allroomtypes_columns') );
    add_filter('manage_bookitall_roomtypes_posts_custom_column', array( $this, 'manage_allroomtypes_custom_fields'), 10, 2);

    add_filter('manage_edit-bookitall_customers_columns', array($this, 'manage_allcustomers_columns') );
    add_filter('manage_bookitall_customers_posts_custom_column', array( $this, 'manage_allcustomers_custom_fields'), 10, 2);        

    add_filter('manage_edit-bookitall_available_columns', array($this, 'manage_allavailable_columns') );
    add_filter('manage_bookitall_available_posts_custom_column', array( $this, 'manage_allavailable_custom_fields'), 10, 2);        

    add_action( 'delete_post', array( $this, 'bookings_sync', 10 ) );

 }


//When removing a post from post type bookitall_bookings (bokningar)
public function bookings_sync ( $post_id ) {
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );   
    wp_die('wow');
    if ( $post_type != 'bookitall_bookings' ) 
    {
        return;
    }

    //more code...
}
```

**The issue is that function bookings_sync is not being fired?** (wp_die('wow') should kill Wordpress and exit everything?)

I've also tried with admin_init hook instead of init hook but still the same issue.

I've also tried deleting the post permanently from trash but still does not work.

**Am I using wrong hook or what is going on?** Help me please :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found it. "Just" a typo...

```
add_action( 'delete_post', array( $this, 'bookings_sync', 10 ) );
```

should be

```
add_action( 'delete_post', array( $this, 'bookings_sync'), 10 );
```